# Datepickerdialog using materialdesign

Tags: android

The `DatePicker` does not pop out with the following code:

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    String date = "You picked the following date: " + dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year;
    TextView dateTextView = null;
    dateTextView.setText(date);

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    final DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
            OneFragment.this,
            now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    );

    btntxt = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btndate);
    btntxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
            dpd.show(fm, "Datepickerdialog");
        }
    });
}
```

Could you guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

Does your `Activity` extend from a `FragmentActivity`?

Here you have a very simple example of `DatePickerDialog` and `TimePickerDialog` which are very similar to your code with those little changes you need to fix your code (also use `getSupportFragmentManager()` better):

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnDateSetListener, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    public static final String DATEPICKER_TAG = "datepicker";
    public static final String TIMEPICKER_TAG = "timepicker";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(this, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), isVibrate());
        final TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(this, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) ,calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false, false);

        findViewById(R.id.dateButton).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                datePickerDialog.setVibrate(isVibrate());
                datePickerDialog.setYearRange(1985, 2028);
                datePickerDialog.setCloseOnSingleTapDay(isCloseOnSingleTapDay());
                datePickerDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), DATEPICKER_TAG);
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.timeButton).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timePickerDialog.setVibrate(isVibrate());
                timePickerDialog.setCloseOnSingleTapMinute(isCloseOnSingleTapMinute());
                timePickerDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TIMEPICKER_TAG);
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            DatePickerDialog dpd = (DatePickerDialog) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(DATEPICKER_TAG);
            if (dpd != null) {
                dpd.setOnDateSetListener(this);
            }

            TimePickerDialog tpd = (TimePickerDialog) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TIMEPICKER_TAG);
            if (tpd != null) {
                tpd.setOnTimeSetListener(this);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isVibrate() {
        return ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxVibrate)).isChecked();
    }

    private boolean isCloseOnSingleTapDay() {
        return ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxCloseOnSingleTapDay)).isChecked();
    }

    private boolean isCloseOnSingleTapMinute() {
        return ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxCloseOnSingleTapMinute)).isChecked();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog, int year, int month, int day) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "new date:" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "new time:" + hourOfDay + "-" + minute, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker/blob/master/datetimepicker-sample/src/com/fourmob/datetimepicker/sample/MainActivity.java